# Need suggestion of a good way to find content of a div

Tags: html, regex, perl, dom

```html
<div class="box notranslate" id="venueHours">
<h5 class="translate">Hours</h5>
<div class="status closed">Currently closed</div>
<div class="hours">
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Sat</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–6:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Fri</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–9:00 PM</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timespan">
      <div class="openTime">
        <div class="days">Sun</div>
        <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–5:00 PM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to capture the contents in all the `<div class="days">` and `<span class="hours">`. I think I'm able to use regular expression in this task. But I also want to learn any funny or professional ways to capture the specific div blocks like this. Thanks.

Comment: You mean to match the whole text inside <div>?

Comment: Do you want the content *enclosed by* those tags or the content *within* those tags?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/Parser.pm

Comment: Never parse XML/HTML/CSV files using regex. Use the existing modules, they are usually mature, stable and well tested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the HTML parsing libraries mentioned elsewhere, other modules have DOM capability too. See for example [`Web::Query`](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) and Mojolicious' [`Mojo::DOM`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM).

Here is an example using `Mojo::DOM` and CSS3 selectors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<<'HTML');
<div class="box notranslate" id="venueHours">
<h5 class="translate">Hours</h5>
<div class="status closed">Currently closed</div>
<div class="hours">
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Sat</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–6:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Fri</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–9:00 PM</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timespan">
      <div class="openTime">
        <div class="days">Sun</div>
        <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–5:00 PM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
HTML

say "div days:";
say $_->text for $dom->find('div.days')->each;

say "\nspan hours:";
say $_->text for $dom->find('span.hours')->each;
```

Or equivalently:

```
say "div days:";
say for $dom->find('div.days')->map(sub{$_->text})->each;

say "\nspan hours:";
say for $dom->find('span.hours')->map(sub{$_->text})->each;
```

Output:

```
div days:
Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Sat
Fri
Sun

span hours:
 10:00 AM–6:00 PM
 10:00 AM–9:00 PM
 10:00 AM–5:00 PM
```

Or to get the times corresponding to the days, you can use the children of the `openTimes` div:

```
say "Open Times:";
say for $dom->find('div.openTime')
            ->map(sub{$_->children->each})
            ->map(sub{$_->text})
            ->each;
```

Output:

```
Open Times:
Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Sat
 10:00 AM–6:00 PM
Fri
 10:00 AM–9:00 PM
Sun
 10:00 AM–5:00 PM
```

Edit: Daxim has posted the analogous `Web::Query` code as a comment, so I will repost it here for better formatting. I haven't tried it, but I trust his code generally. Assuming the HTML is in a variable `$html`:

```
use Web::Query qw(); 
my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html($html);
say "div days:";
say for $w->find('div.days')->text; 
say "\nspan hours:"; 
say for $w->find('span.hours')->text; 
say "Open Times:"; 
$w->find('div.openTime')->each(sub { say for $_->find('*')->text });
```

Comment: For comparison, Web::Query's API is less verbose: `use Web::Query qw(); my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html($html); say for $w->find('div.days')->text; say "\nspan hours:"; say for $w->find('span.hours')->text; say "Open Times:"; $w->find('div.openTime')->each(sub { say for $_->find('*')->text });`

Answer (score 3):

Use modules specific to this task: [HTML::Parser](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aParser), [HTML::Tree](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTree) and the like.

Answer (score -1):

regular expression to match Status "Currently closed":

```
/<\/h5><div[^>]*>([^<]*)/
```

to match days:

```
/<div class="days">([^<]*)/
```

to match hours:

```
/<span class="hours">([^<]*)/
```

Comment: why you downvote my solution? It is faster then using DOM libraries. Just check memory usage and time the script executes.

Comment: LOL I didn't downvote anyone, I know this will work. Good job and thanks.

Comment: Maybe because question specifically mentions that he's aware about regexp and want to hear about OTHER options?

Comment: Downvoted for violation of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9719 .  Regexes are a bad solution.

Comment: that post has no valid reasons explained. "very time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers..." What???? :D
Ok, if this sounds like a reason, read that -> "Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex."

Comment: thanks Oleg, I got the point, the answer coundn't be in regexp. My bad :)